# Can't input negative integer into SQLite table

Tags: python, sqlite, flask

I'm trying to put a negative integer into my sqlite database but it's not being inserted for some reason.

I get the error:

`TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'`

And when I checked with printing the value, I find that it's empty.

This is the command I use to insert to the table:

```py
db.execute(
    "INSERT INTO history (id,date,symbol,shares,price) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)",
    session["user_id"],
    time,
    request.form.get("symbol").upper(),
    request.form.get("shares") * -1,
    price,
)
```

`request.form.get("shares")` is a number input from a HTML form.

And I use this to make the table:

```py
db.execute(
    "CREATE TABLE history (id int, date varchar(255), symbol varchar(9), shares int, price int)"
)
```

I've tried surrounding `request.form.get("shares")` with an `int()` but it didn't work.

Positive integers work fine.

Comment: Instead of multiplying by -1, can you try `-int(request.form.get("shares"))`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is exactly what the error is saying. The returned data from the request form is returning a non digit type. Any input is returned as a string and then needs to be redefined. If you try doing

```py
print(type(request.form.get("shares")
```

You can see the type of the result and work from there. What @Jack Deeth said in his answer will work. You can also always do the math before insert and declare as an int beforehand.

Comment: thanks, I figured out that it was because I didn't clear out my table after changing my request.form.get("shares") to int.